# Problems with contact form, phpmailer() and gmailadress

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer, contact-form

I had problems with the contact form and therefore I read that phpmailer is very usefull. Unforunately I am already stuck for hours and I don't know how to get further anymore.

I want to test whether I can send an email (after that I want to connect the email to a form submission, but with no succes so far. I am using PHPmailer 5.2.0 and I use the code below (while using WAMPSERVER for testing. Does anybody know what I should adjust?

I already used many examples (including from stackoverflow, but I am just missing something. Do you see what goes wrong? Every time I get the error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Er is een onherstelbare fout opgetreden tijdens het zoeken in de database. (0) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Thanks in advance!!

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contactformulier.html');
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "test@gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "test@gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "test@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('test@gmail.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("test@gmail.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "test@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");



if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your mail host name is wrong and AFAIK Gmail doesn't accept connections on port 26. There is a [sample code snippet](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail) on the PHPMailer web site that shows how to connect to Gmail. I suggest you follow that.

Comment: Thanks for you help Mike, I tried that one as well, but that caused even more errors... What do you mean with AFAIK?

Comment: The worxware site is out of date - use the example from the current repo: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike commented, you've used some very strange values. Follow [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) from the PHPMailer repo, which essentially involves these settings:

```
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer - there have been a lot of bug fixes since that version, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Otherwise, simple connection failures are usually down to DNS or local network problems rather than anything in PHPMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, now the mailing is working correctly! I had a wrong port and host (I askerd my provider).

Something else, do you guys know how to get back to the webpage after sending the email? I thought that is not that hard, but I have a hard time with it...